# Cisco ASA 5510 IP Hairpin NAT

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ip

I’ve been going round in circles for the last few days trying to accomplish this:

I’ve not had much experience with cisco routers, this is a ASA 5510 running 8.2 (old command structure).

In a nutshell I want to translate a LAN request for one of our external ips to the internal webserver (I think this is also called hair pinning).

We have a block of 8 external IP’s

i.i.i.97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 210, 211

Our interface running config is:

```
interface Ethernet0/0
nameif OUTSIDE
 security-level 0
 ip address 213.106.251.100 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.22.16.25 255.255.240.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no nameif
 security-level 50
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/2.23
 vlan 23
 nameif GuestWireless
 security-level 10
 ip address 172.22.225.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
```

On the inside I have a server on 10.22.16.34 which I want to expose ports 21, 80, 8000, 8082 to internet clients.  However I need internal LAN clients when requesting the external IP i.i.i.98 to be redirected to 10.22.16.34

I’ve tried lots of guides but run into problems each time, I would be very grateful for some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Any option for split DNS instead (pointing the DNS name to the internal IP on the local DNS server)? Very easy solution.

Comment: right this is what I was thinking. (just read your answer).

Answer (score 0):

It could look as below:

your default dynamic PAT for LAN users to access internet:

```
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 10.22.16.0 255.255.240.0
nat (inside) 1 172.22.225.0 255.255.255.0
```

Than Static NAT for server:

```
static (inside,outside) [PUBLICIP] [INTERNALIP] netmask 255.255.255.255
```

You need enable same security interface traffic:

```
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
```

Than another nat inside to inside:

```
static (inside,inside) [PUBLICIP] 10.22.16.0 netmask 255.255.240.0
static (inside,inside) [PUBLICIP] 172.22.225.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and just add:

```
global (inside) 1 interface
```

That's should be pretty much all. Don't have device on 8.2 to test it.

You may want to check out [this](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-firewalls/1150-cisco-asa-firewall-nat-reflection-loopback-hairpinning-configuration.html) or [this](http://mike-knight.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/asa-82-and-hairpin-nat.html) post.

Comment: Thanks.. when I try the 

static (inside,inside) [PUBLICIP] 10.22.16.0 netmask 255.255.240.0

I receive - 

global address overlaps with mask

Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason line breaks do not work???

Comment: Is your PUBLIC IP included within 10.22.16.0/20?

Comment: no public ip's are all 213.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Respectfully, I think you're going about it wrong. Web servers are targeted with web addresses, namely, DNS records. So, your server might be mysever.mydomain.com. All you gotta do is set your DNS up appropriately and resolve inside users to the inside address. So, it's a DNS configuration issue.